# Jade adding apostrophe in output

Tags: node.js, express, pug

For some reason this Jade template is adding apostrophes around variable outputs, regardless of what I try. You can see how it's saved in the document at the bottom. Any ideas?

```
div.col-md-4.col-xs-12
        div#currentImg
            img(src=user.profileImg,class="currentImg")
```

Outputs as:

```
<img src="'/uploads/e3670578cc1f0a235ae9686622f37d2c.jpg'" class="currentImg">
```

For the document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5547e78c28d405cc236d4a02"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2015-05-07T20:20:16.537Z"
    },
    "created_at": "Mon May 04 2015 17:41:32 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
    "admin": false,
    "lastName": "#####",
    "firstName": "#####",
    "email": "#####",
    "password": "#####",
    "callsign": "#####",
    "uid": "#####",
    "logPublic": true,
    "profilePublic": true,
    "__v": 0,
    "profileImg": "/uploads/cf431a1d4cb451d9fb806a987845e8c3.png"
}
```

Comment: Does it do this in other circumstances?

Comment: @tadman I have other variables output on the page, none of those have apostrophes around them. They are all output in the same way.

Comment: What version of Jade are you using? I can't appear to duplicate this behavior in the latest version. http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/GJoKQr?editors=100

Comment: @AlexFord - I'm using Jade v1.9.2

Comment: Well that's the version on codepen I believe :/

Comment: Just to double check, I did it locally: http://i.imgur.com/d0PxDbx.png. Still not able to reproduce the issue. Definitely used 1.9.2.

Comment: I just tried this and cannot reproduce on 1.9.2 as well...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your JSON data is indeed correct and does not have that erroneous `'` in it, there is no reason that this error should be occurring in Jade.

Check out the [codepen](http://codepen.io/michael-hamilton/pen/zGrYRB) (click on View Compiled).

One suggestion would be to use HTML in the line of Jade where you are trying to create the image, and set it's `src` attrubute using `#{user.profileImg}` as such:

```
<img src="#{user.profileImg}" class="currentImg">
```